# What's the best way to get credentials in a JAX-RS Application?

Tags: java, security, rest, jakarta-ee, restlet

I'm working on a small piece of middleware based on RESTlet that's providing a REST API to several back-end systems.

There for, my JAX-RS Application requires credentials for some of its methods to authenticate calls to back-end systems using (clear text) user name and password.

So far, I found a lot of documentation on Authorization/Authentication, but all of it only goes as far as validating access to methods and providing user groups. None of it seems to give me the possibility to pass the users' credentials to the actual methods. Is there a nice way to inject them without being REST framework dependent?

Comment: I don't understand what you are having trouble with. You can submit any information you want to a RESTful call, including a username and password. All you need to do is add them to your model objects.

Answer (score 0):

A common (and not very secure unless you're on HTTPS) strategy  is to put them in the HTTP Request Header if you just want plain authentication. On the server side you can use those values and do whatever you want with them, including evaluating access to the requested service. If you use JAX-RS is relatively simple to create a utility method that does that.

If you also want to ensure integrity you may want to include an hash obtained hashing the concatenation of all param string representation with a simmetric key (known both by client and server). On the server side you recompute the hash to check if the request has been tampered or not. In this way even if an eavesdropper get your credentials sniffing the netwkork traffic he would have difficult times in sending fake requests or tampering a correct one.

Comment: So using basic Auth to send it via Header and parse the Headers is the way to go; maybe over HTTPs to make sure the header is encrypted? Isn't there a nicer mechanism to do that?

Comment: I'm not pretending to say that "this is the way to go" but it's what  I do when I need a simple yet efficient mechanism. OAuth is way nicer, but the setup it's more complex.